# JavaScript + InDesign: Find a word in a .indd document and write a .txt file with page number locations

Tags: javascript, find, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm running into a problem while trying to execute a script to find a specific word — in this case the name of a project within a book — and write the page numbers of all its occurrences in my InDesign document to a .txt file.

Problem: For whatever reason, the returned "parentPage.name" values are listed out of order (i.e.: its occurrence on p. 184 appears in the list before p. 11, for example, etc.)

I'm not sure if it's related to this code (below) or elsewhere:

```
pg_nr = found_txt.parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.name;
```

If anyone has any ideas for how to resolve this, that'd be great. Thank you!

A full version of my code is below:

```
main ();
function main() {

var file_name = new Date() + "-Title-Project_Name-Page_Location";
var filepath = "~/Desktop/" + file_name + ".txt";
var write_file = File(filepath);
    write_file = new File(filepath);
    var write_text;
        write_text = write_file.open('w', undefined, undefined);
        write_file.encoding = "UTF-8";
        write_file.lineFeed = "Macintosh";
        #target indesign;
        var doc = app.activeDocument;
            app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
            app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
            app.findChangeTextOptions.includeLockedLayersForFind = true;
            app.findChangeTextOptions.includeLockedStoriesForFind = true;
            app.findChangeTextOptions.includeHiddenLayers = false;
            app.findChangeTextOptions.includeMasterPages = false;
            app.findChangeTextOptions.includeFootnotes = true;
            app.findChangeTextOptions.caseSensitive = false;
            app.findChangeTextOptions.wholeWord = false;
            project_name = "Project Name";
            app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = project_name;
                find_txt = doc.findText();
                for (var i = 0; i < find_txt.length; i++) {
                    if (find_txt[i].contents == project_name) {
                        found_txt = find_txt[i];
                        pg_nr = found_txt.parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.name;
                        write_file.writeln(project_name + " : p. " + pg_nr + "\r\r");
                        }
                    }
            app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
            app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    write_file.close();
return;
}
```

Comment: @usr2564301 Hey. Thanks! That's perfect — you're right: one instance of the name did appear on the PB, which would explain why it worked when I removed the call for pagination. Deleted that instance, and the code runs without any errors. The second problem does still exist and, yes, they are in disconnected text frames throughout the book.

Comment: Note: There are actually four instances where the searched-for word is repeated within a story/text thread, thus the same page number is returned a couple times. This doesn't bother me, per se ... but getting them to return in numerically chronological order would be great.

Comment: You may need to store the values in an array and sort them before writing to your text file

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Okay, thanks. I'll look into that. Oddly enough, however, I've noticed that even the native "SortParagraphs.jsx" file in InDesign doesn't sort text numerically very well ... as it does the standard computational error of putting page 123 after 11, and before 15. Might be beyond my level of understanding, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: That's because it is sorting strings and not numbers

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Okay, thanks. I'll look into how to build an array from my retrieved "parentPage.name" results.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to do that, actually ...

Comment: Go by the parent page index instead of the parent page name - the index is always in sequence of layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the script modified to push results to an array, and then sort them by the order of appearance in the document.

Clearly the answer is way late... But hopefully it's of use in the future.

```
main ();
function main() {
    var arrResults = [];
    #target indesign;
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeLockedLayersForFind = true;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeLockedStoriesForFind = true;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeHiddenLayers = false;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeMasterPages = false;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.includeFootnotes = true;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.caseSensitive = false;
    app.findChangeTextOptions.wholeWord = false;
    project_name = "Project Name";
    app.findTextPreferences.findWhat = project_name;
        find_txt = doc.findText();
        for (var i = 0; i < find_txt.length; i++) {
            if (find_txt[i].contents == project_name) {
                found_txt = find_txt[i];
                pg_nr = found_txt.parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.name;
                pg_index = found_txt.parentTextFrames[0].parentPage.documentOffset;
                // pushes results into an array of objects
                arrResults[arrResults.length] = {"project_name":project_name,"page_number":pg_nr,"page_index":pg_index};
                }
            }
    app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
    // sorts array by the document offset (order of appearance in document)
    arrResults = arrResults.sort(function(a,b){return a.page_index>b.page_index});
    // convert object to string
    for(var i = 0; i<arrResults.length; i++){
        arrResults[i] = "project:"+arrResults[i].project_name+", pg:"+arrResults[i].page_number;
        }
    var file_name = new Date() + "-Title-Project_Name-Page_Location";
    var filepath = "~/Desktop/" + file_name + ".txt";
    var write_file = new File(filepath);
    var write_text;
    write_text = write_file.open('w');
    write_file.encoding = "UTF-8";
    write_file.lineFeed = "Macintosh";
    write_file.write(arrResults.join("\n"));
    return;
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks! No problem in lateness ... it still wasn't solved. However, upon running the script as you've modified it here, it simply returns "[object Object]" multiple times in the .txt file — one for each found instance, basically. Thoughts? Would be great if you could help me resolve this once and for all! Thank you.

Comment: Haha I'll fix it. Sorry.